# How to load a data set

Tags: r, dataset

I have to load a data set in R. I have installed multiple packages but am not sure which one a certain data set belongs to. I am just beginning to code, so I do not know much about R. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't know which package the data set belongs to either, because you haven't told us the name of the data set you are looking for. Perhaps you could let us know this? It's difficult to know what kind of help you'd be looking for without this piece of information. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Allan, the data set is BullTroutRML2.

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me, perhaps to somebody else it does? There are many datasets and packages with data out there, it's difficult to keep track. If you know, please share from which package you are getting that dataset.

Comment: Hi r2evans. I only have the data set name BullTroutRML2 and Libraries: plyr, FSA, FSAdata, magrittr,  dplyr, plotrix, ggplot2, moments. This is the only information I have.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. To find out more about a package, sometimes you can google "cran" and the package name (also quoted), such as `"cran" "FSAdata"`, that helps google narrow down its wide scope (sometimes adding `"r"` is necessary too, though not always). With this, you should be able to find which of those has that dataset. (Based on the name and, I think you can safely skip `plyr`, `ggplot2`, `dplyr`, and `magrittr` as candidates, so check the others first.)

Comment: Yeah it's in the FSAdata package: https://github.com/fishR-Core-Team/FSAdata

Comment: First load the package FSAdata using `library(FSAdata)`, then you will be able to use the dataset BullTroutRML2. Eg `head(BullTroutRML2)`